# nginx rewrite rules for cached images

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite

we are currently migratiing all services from apache2 to nginx but are currently stuck with a specific rewrite rule.
The rule in apache is checking if a cached image/thumbnail exists and if so, delivers the output directly.
otherwise it will rewrite the request to an image-processor.

```
# if cached version exists, output directly
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(Guest|Member|avatar|tagged|thumb)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/$1/%{QUERY_STRING}.jpg -f
RewriteRule (.*)\.jpg$ /cache/$1/%{QUERY_STRING}.jpg [L]

# otherwise redirect all jpg-image-requests to processing
# script if they are not in cache dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache
RewriteRule \.jpg$ /image_processing.php [QSA,L]
```

we tried several try_files approaches but we failed so far.
could someone please help in porting this rewrite rules to nginx?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a whole lot easier if you showed us what you'd already tried, but off the top of my head, something like this should do the trick (assuming you've got a vhost-wide `root` parameter set; if not, you'll want to fix that anyway):

```
location ~ ^.*/.*\.jpg$ {
    try_files $uri @image_processor;
}

location @image_processor {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $documentroot/image_processing.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/home/user/something/php.sock;
}
```

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve in that first block; I can't comprehend why you'd use the query string like that.